# How can I embed the Roomle Rubens Configurator in a WPF WebView2?

Tags: c#, wpf, window, roomle

I would like to embed the  [Roomle Rubens Configurator](https://www.roomle.com/de/blog/roomle-rubens-configurator) in a WPF dialog of a Windows desktop application.
I want to use a [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) control and have followed the instructions for [Get started with WebView2 in WPF apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/wpf) to create a desktop application.
I also know how to embed the configurator in a website. A nice documentation can be found here: [Embedding Integration](https://docs.roomle.com/web/embedding/).

My question is how do I put things together?

I would like to display the configurator as documented in the WebView of my application and communicate with it. I want to set and change parameters in my WPF UI, send the parameters to the web application and update the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it step by step:

1. Create a WPF dialog with a WebView2 control. See [Get started with WebView2 in WPF apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/wpf)
2. Create a resource folder for the web content and add *roomle-configurator-api.es.min.js*. The files can be found here: [Roomle Rubens Configurator Embedding Lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@roomle/embedding-lib).
   (In the example the name of the folder is *resource\wwwroot*)
3. Get the quick start *html* from here: [Embedding Integration - Copy & Paste without package manager](https://docs.roomle.com/web/embedding/#copy-paste-without-package-manager).
   Create an *index.html* file in the resource folder and paste the content from the quick start guide.
4. Establish a mapping between a virtual host name and the path of the web resources folder. Set the source of the web view by the local host:

   ```cs
   async private Task InitializeAsync(WebView2 webView)
   {
       string hostName = "rubens.example"
       string localResourcePath = Path.Join(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"resource\wwwroot");

       await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
       webView.CoreWebView2.SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping(
           hostName, localResourcePath, CoreWebView2HostResourceAccessKind.DenyCors);
       webView.Source = new Uri($"https://{hostName}/index.html");
   }
   ```

   [EnsureCoreWebView2Async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.wpf.webview2.ensurecorewebview2async?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1056-prerelease) wait for `CoreWebView2` initialization. The method explicitly triggers initialization of the control's CoreWebView2.
   [SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.setvirtualhostnametofoldermapping?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1056-prerelease) sets a mapping between a virtual host name and a folder path to make available to web sites via that host name.
5. Add an event listener to the host app. In the following example, *width* and *height* data is retrieved from the event and set to the corresponding attributes of the root component with `configurator.extended.setParameterOfRootComponent`:

   ```js
   window.chrome.webview.addEventListener('message', arg => {
       if (arg.data.width) {
           configurator.extended.setParameterOfRootComponent({ "key": "width" }, arg.data.width.toString());
       }
       if (arg.data.height) {
           configurator.extended.setParameterOfRootComponent({ "key": "height" }, arg.data.height.toString());
       }
   });
   ```
6. Set events to the host app:

   ```cs
   public void ChangeHeight(WebView2 webView, int newHeight) =>
       webView.CoreWebView2.PostWebMessageAsJson($"{{ \"height\" : {newHeight} }}");
   ```

   [CoreWebView2.PostWebMessageAsJson](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.postwebmessageasjson?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1056-prerelease) posts the specified webMessageAsJson to the top level document in this WebView.
   [CoreWebView2.PostWebMessageAsString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.postwebmessageasstring?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1056-prerelease) posts a message that is a simple String rather than a JSON string representation of a JavaScript object.

The full example can be found in the GitHub repository: [Roomle/roomle-configurator-wpf-cs-example](https://github.com/Roomle/roomle-configurator-wpf-cs-example)

[image]